# linux + ssh is hung on SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, rhel, ifconfig

We can't ssh from one Linux server to other server in spite of ping working.

When debugging it, we see that ssh is stuck  on `debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent`
and not reached to `SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received`

How can we explain that?

Until now we checked the following:

port 22 - is open ( verified by telnet ) , Firewall is stopped , the same on iptables

```
ssh -v 10.12.187.23
OpenSSH_3.6.1p1, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090702f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: Connecting to localhost [10.12.187.23] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_3.6.1p1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_3.6.1p1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.6.1p1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

other example

```
ssh -vv worker01
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to worker01 [102.164.35.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Comment: Is that the end of the debugging? The program doesn't exit or produce an error, or time out? ... Also, in both examples, the OpenSSH client is very old...  6.6.1 was released in March, 2014... and 3.6.1 was circa 2003.